# Dll file is missing When i Install Wamp server

Tags: dll, wampserver, missing-data

Hai Guys GoodNoon To all.

When I trying to install Wamp Server2.5v in Windows 7 64bit OS I get this error

```
The Program can't start Because MSVCR110.dll is missing from your computer Try       Reinstalling...
```

I googled For this Problem.. But no Solution is helping for me ..

1)I dwonloaded dll file and pasted in related path,

2)Also Downloaded VC10 SP1 vcredist_x64.exe and insatlled

3)also downloaded Both version 2.5 2nd 2.4. for both 64 and 32 bit OS.

Nothing is so far solve that issue.Please help me install Wamp server. Advance Thanks Too All..

Comment: As the message says `MSVCR110.dll` then you are missing the `MSVC Redist 2012` ( and maybe othres as well. There is a message on the WAMPServer download page telling you this runtime library needs to be installed before you install WampServer 2.5

Comment: First: Stick with the 32bit WAMPServer. There are no benefits to using the 64bit version and in fact PHP(64) is not a complete 64bit port and is still considered Experimental, it even says so on the php.net site.

Comment: If you are still getting the same error then you have not installed the correct C/C++ libraries. Try the install again and if it offers a repair option, say yes.

Answer (score 2):

**msvcr110.dll** is a c run time library file that is needed to be present in your system . just download this file and placed it in **C-> windows -> system32** 
and uninstall wamp then install again 
Note : if it it give error for another file missing . download those files and proceed as same 
other files may be : 

 msvcr100.dll 

msvcp110.dll 
msvcp100.dll

Answer (score 1):

```
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123608
```

Read this, there are some solution on their forum, and comments of other people who have the same problem.

Maybe you missing Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64) or Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)

Comment: Thanks fro Reply , I downloaded and installed also ..Again i reinstall the wamp .. it shows Same error..

Comment: Did you Downlaod AND install all the required dll's i.e. 2005/2008/2010/2012. If you are still using WAMPServer 64bit its a good idea to download the 32bit and 64bit versions of all these C++ runtime libraries.